# Missing route between host and bridged VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, routing, qemu, bridging

i have the following setup:

1. physical Host Machine Lubuntu 19.04
2. virtual Machine Ubuntu 18.04

i managed to create bridged networking between the hosts network and the vm network, so their both in the same. Every machine in the network is able to communicate with the vm exept for the host machine.

**Interface List - Host**

```
root:~# ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.100/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global enp0s31f6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: macvtap0@enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:0f:c7:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:c71f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**Route list of Host:**

```
root:~# ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100
```

---

**Interface list of VM:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:0f:c7:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.155/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global ens3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:c71f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

So i thought the host has to know that he should access the vm 192.168.1.155 via the device(virt.bridge) "macvtap0@enp0s31f6" and added the following route: 
**192.168.1.155 dev macvtap0 scope link**

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.100
192.168.1.155 dev macvtap0 scope link
.
root:~# ping 192.168.1.155
PING 192.168.1.155 (192.168.1.155) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.100 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Unfortunately that didnt work and im quiet sure that i didnt understand the needed syntax / knowledge with ip route yet.

So could anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using `macvtap` for bridge networking.

```
3: macvtap0@enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:0f:c7:1f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe0f:c71f/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Keep in mind that although by using `macvtap` you can connect to guest OS(in your case Ubuntu 18.04) from other network devices but you actually can not connect to it by using your host computer(again in your case Lubuntu 19.04).

So what is the solution?

Well the thing is you actually need to create `bridge-adapter` so that you can connect through both `host` and other network computers and there are multiple ways to achieve this. I'm using `network manager` in my case but you can choose others as well.

- In your terminal type `# nmtui`
- Select `Edit a connection` and press `Enter`
- Select `Add` and `Enter`
- Type your `Profile name` and `Device`. For easier configuration keep both as `br01`
- Then under `Slaves` select `Add` and give it `Profile name` as well `brslave01`.
- And in `Device` section type your `Ethernet` device id(in your case it is `enp0s31f6`)
- Select `Ok`
- And `Ok` again and exit the the Text UI for controlling network manager.

Now you need to reset the network and you can achieve this by simply rebooting or

`# service networking restart` or
`# systemctl restart network-manager`
whichever is applicable for you.

Then you can go to your existing KVM and make sure it is shut down. Then add a network device under shared device and type your new network id that is `bro1`.

After that remove old network that is `macvtap` and configure your guest OS if necessary.

That's it and it should work like a charm. Shout out if you need any help.